# How do I search a file line by line and then copy a line to a list if it contains a certain string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, append

I know how to read a whole file into a list line by line, but I cannot figure out the syntax for searching a file for a string and grabbing the whole line, and then appending that to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    mylist = [line for line in f if search_string in line]
```

This will preserve the newlines at the end of every line since that's how iterating a file works. To remove the newlines, call `line.rstrip('\n')` before appending:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    mylist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f if search_string in line]
```

Other options are `line.rstrip()` to remove all trailing spaces including newlines, and `line.strip()` to remove all trailing *and* leading spaces, including of course the newline.

Comment: Using `in` is even better than `find()`, or at least more Pythonic. Good answer

Comment: @ahota. Thanks. Not to mention comprehension vs explicit loop.

Comment: @Mad Physicist - This worked perfectly except it is putting a newline char at the end of each element. How do I strip the \n?

Comment: @JakeMiller `line.strip()` in the list comprehension

Comment: @Jake. Updated.

Comment: @Jake. The proper thing to do here would be to select the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it. That will remove your question from the unanswered queue and give you and I a couple of points.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use `string.find()` on each line as you parse the file: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

For example:

```
with open('filename', 'r') as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    if line.find('search_string') != -1:
      # do stuff
```